# installing drools planner in eclipse: The constructor IntConstraintOccurrence(String, Object[]) is ambiguous

Tags: jboss, eclipse-plugin, drools, drools-planner, optaplanner

I have been trying to install Drools planner. I downloaded it, installed the plug-in, created a run-time, and created a new project.  However, I run into build errors in the rules file:  The constructor IntConstraintOccurrence(String, Object[]) is ambiguous.  This code works perfectly fine on my friend's computer (also using eclipse), so I know it is not an error in the code, but I have not been able to figure what is the problem.  Anyone have this problem before?

Comment: Good news is that in 6.0.0, the IntConstraintOccurrence will be replaced by the much faster scoreHolder.addConstraintMatch, which doesn't need the causes parameter (it figures it out automatically)

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to OptaPlanner (= [Drools Planner](http://www.optaplanner.org/community/droolsPlannerRenamed.html)) 6.0.x and [avoid the Object[] parameter all together](http://blog.athico.com/2013/04/score-drl-faster-and-easier-in.html).